# Have an button reset and start a countdown timer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer

I am trying to begin a countdown timer when a button is clicked. I have searched and found a few different items, but nothing that seems to function.

I have different buttons throughout the domain that will set different times (IE: 120 seconds, 60 seconds, etc). The display is in the same spot on every page ( `div` in the top right of the loaded page ) so I was wanting to use an external js `scripts/timer.js`

I can use `<div id="timer"></div>` to place the timer.

My questions: How do I call the function to start the timer. What is a good suggested script for said timer when the amount of time can change and it has to carry over pages (I've been using `$_SESSION['x']`to pass information between .php

```
<div class="headertopgab">
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px">
        Galactic Credits: 
        <?php echo "&Ccedil;".$_SESSION['galacticCredits']; ?>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 50px; float: left">
        <?php echo "".$_SESSION['currentLocation']; ?>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
        <div id="time">10</div>  <!-- this is where I want the countdown-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a broad question, but a push in the right direction is that you need the timer code to be on the page in JavaScript. But if you also need that value on the server, you are going to have to pass the timer value to/from the server -- possibly through hidden inputs in a FORM tag.

Comment: more specifically I'm looking for the countdown script and any libraries I need listed. I can't download them and install them locally as the server is not on my machine.

Comment: You don't need any libraries. Just Google the JavaScript "setTimeout()" method. There are numerous examples. Just remember to post back your times if you need them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this

```
var countdown;
var counter = function(){
    var time = parseInt($('#time').text());
    if (time !== 0){
        $('#time').text(time - 1);
    }else{
        clearInterval(countdown);
    }
}
countdown = setInterval(counter , 1000);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uL50cqmw/)